# Covariance of matrix with element entries as vectors

Tags: covariance

Suppose there is a matrix A with m rows and n columns. Each element is a 3 dimensional vector. This 3 dimensional vector have values of different orders. Can we calculate covariance of such matrix ?

Comment: It sounds like the only issue here is the choice of how one structures such data. Look at time, for instance, if one is interested in describing an AR-1 process, you might merge a time-series with it's lagged effect. For AR-2, merge two lagged effects. For universal kriging, merge a point, it's lagged effect, and adjacent samples: just one way of representing correlations in 4 dimensional data. Covariance is, by definition, only computed between two random variables.